# How to know the percent loaded of a PDF file on PDFjs

Tags: javascript, loader, pdf.js

Is there any way to know the percentage of loading a PDF file in PDFJS?

I curently have the following code:

```
var filename = 'your_pdf_file.pdf';
PDFJS.getDocument(filename).then(function (pdf) {
    console.info('File loaded:' + filename)
}).catch(function(pdf){
    console.error('File not found:' + filename)
});
```

The problem is that I'm only able to know when the file was loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use progressCallback parameter in getDocument:

```js
var progressCallback = function (progress) {
    // progress object contains "total" and "loaded" properties
}

var filename = 'your_pdf_file.pdf';
PDFJS.getDocument(filename, null, null, progressCallback).then(function (pdf) {
    console.info('File loaded:' + filename)
}).catch(function(pdf){
    console.error('File not found:' + filename)
});
```

Comment: If it helps you, set the answer is accepted and/or vote up it.